# ¿detectar cuando la pantalla cambia con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, eventos

Hola se que esto es muy simple y que lo tengo que hacer con un evento pero no se como.

Lo que busco es algo como esto.

```
$(window).resize(funciton(e){
   console.log(e)
});
```

Pero necesito usar javascript dado que no puedo usar jquery en mis proyectos.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', changeScreen);

function changeScreen(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

Algo asi se me ocurre.

Comment: window.addEventListener("resize", function(event) {
    console.log(document.body.clientWidth + ' wide by ' + document.body.clientHeight+' high');
})

Comment: cual es la diferencia con screen.width ?

Comment: document.body.clientHeight retorna el height del documento html
screen.height retorna el height de navegador

Answer (score -1):

Cuál sería la pregunta ? Me parece que tu addEventListener funcionaría con el evento "resize".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events